# Symfony 2.1 custom field for check boxes

Tags: php, symfony

I have used custom form field tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html and it created a gender selection in radio buttons. So far so good.

I need to show checkboxes with multiple selection. How can I add thhem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This field may be rendered as one of several different HTML fields, depending on the expanded and multiple options as shown in this table http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons from Symfony book.